# Why doesn't my generated project create an import library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have this cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.20)
project (DllTest)
if (MSVC)
    add_compile_definitions(UNICODE _UNICODE)
endif()


add_library(mydll SHARED dllmain.cpp)


add_executable(test_dll testmain.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_dll PUBLIC mydll)
```

when I generate projects using this cmake test file and compile the code, I am getting this error:

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'Debug\mydll.lib'
```

I searched all of the build directories and I can not find any mydll.lib.

How can I create a Dll and linked it to another project using cmake?

Comment: Show your code (see [mre]). Did you export any symbols from your ddlmain header file? What version of MSVC are you using? Have you tried using [the `dir /s` command to search for the file](/q/8066679)?

Comment: If you don't export symbols from your code for the dll you don't get an import library. This may help: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @Tom what on earth does that have to do with this link error?

Comment: Once you've provided your [mre], if the problem is really that you haven't exported anything, I can write up an answer post. Tom's answer will work, but I'd suggest exporting symbols "case-by-case", which CMake can help you out with via its [`GenerateExportHeader`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) module.

Comment: @user The problem as you mentioned was that I did not export anything. By exporting some functions, the problem is solved, So if you create an answer based on your comment, then I will accept it.

Comment: I can't answer and don't need to answer because another Q&A should already sufficiently answer this question (this has been closed as a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Create dlls on Windows without declspec() using new CMake export all feature](https://www.kitware.com/create-dlls-on-windows-without-declspec-using-new-cmake-export-all-feature/#:%7E:text=The%20feature%20is%20implemented%20in%20%EE%80%80CMake%EE%80%81%20via%20a,%EE%80%80all%EE%80%81%20%EE%80%80symbols%EE%80%81%20to%20be%20exported%20from%20the%20DLL), the author said:

> A shared library on Windows known as a DLL (dynamic linked library)
> requires changes to the source code or an explicit listing of all the
> symbols that the dll will export.  The compilers on Linux/UNIX have
> the ability to export all symbols in a shared library automatically.
> On Windows, you must either use compiler directives __declspec(import)
> and __declspec(export) to declare which symbols are exported/imported
> from a shared library, or you must create a module definition text
> file (.def) with a list of all the symbols you want to export and pass
> that file to the linker. The feature is implemented in CMake via a new
> target property, WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS. When enabled, this
> property causes CMake to automatically create a .def  file with all
> symbols found in the input .obj files for a SHARED library on Windows.
> The .def file will be passed to the linker causing all symbols to be
> exported from the DLL.

**So** add  `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)`  in your CMakeLists or run  `cmake -DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE` , the link error will be fixed.

Comment: That's one way to do it :/ but not the only way. Exporting unnecessary symbols has size impact and could be considered a form of breaking encapsulation. And the asker hasn't even provided enough clarification to be sure that this is the problem (although I'd wager it is). Maybe be a little less trigger happy?

Comment: Don't do that, `CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` is a workaround for existing libraries which don't properly handle visibility of their symbols, not a proper long term solution.